# How to play audio in background?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

My project is a game with cards and it's not ready yet since I need several things done first.

For the time being, I succeded in using the following to play a music theme for my game:

> < MediaElement x:Name="sound" Source="/MusicTheme/musictheme.wma" AutoPlay="True" />

The problem is, that the moment I navigate to an other page, the music stops. I tried to re-write the same code on the 2nd page so it keeps looping for the whole project but that didn't work.

Secondly, I want my project to give the user the ability to use 2 buttons that will be controlling the music. For example I made another page that refers to Options with two buttons "ON" and "OFF".

I made the same thing using Blend 4 and triggers, to place on my buttons with a Sound "click". But I can't make them all turn OFF or ON again from another "page".

Any help with that would be wonderful.

Answer (score 1):

A `MediaElement` is an appropariate way to play such content but rather have it existing only within the scope of a page (which will be torn down when the user navigates away from the page), either create the `MediaElement` in code at an application level or create it in XAML by overriding the `PhoneApplicationFrame`.

For an exmaple on how to do this see http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/windowsphone7series/thread/3ee75fd6-cc9c-4c0f-ad8e-d5d0fdfe77a4

You can then reference the control directly from whichever page you wish to manipulate/control playback.

Comment: I didn't get it could you be a little bit more specific?
And what about the buttons

Comment: I didnt get it right,could you be more specific?
And how about the ON or OFF button's? Any code solution for this? How i could be able to shut them all down ?

Answer (score 0):

I just have seen this topic in the [Microsoft Code Samples section](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff431744%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) for Windows Phone. I could recommend this to you, if you just had started with wp7! Here is the direct link: [How to: Play Background Audio for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202978%28v=vs.92%29.aspx)

Comment: this thing is just an audio player,i dont want my app to have a player in it,i want just a music to play in the background and to give the user the option to MUTE it or TURN IT ON when he needs from a seperate  "example.xaml"... :(

Comment: this example provides you all things you need to do that, add a Windows Phone Audio Playback Agent, with your background music. This agent can play your music in a loop. In the clickevents of the buttons you call e.g. BackgroundAudioPlayer.Instance.Pause() to stop the music playing. I don't know a way, to implement this inside the page.

Comment: still not helping.. :/ plus i cant find  Windows Phone Audio Playback Agent to do what the "guide" ask's of me.. i need something else.

Comment: An audio playback agent is not an appropariate solution to playing audion only within an application. It is for playing audio even when the application isn't in the foreground.